# Web Browser control not working for installed application using PowerBuilder 2021

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

In my powerbuilder 2021 devolvement environment the web control works fine and it navigates to the desired URLs Correctly.
when I release complied version of my application to the user this web browser control does not work.
sometimes it displays blank space and another time application closed. I put all the web browser related dll's in application path its is not work. I use Windows10 OS.
what can I try doing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 web browser controls in a test window of a PB 2019R3 application.
The first one opens a local php script on wampserver64 with data coming from a SqL-Anywhere Network server. The second one open another php page and the third one connects to a website with full address. Everything works.
My default browser is Firefox 106.0.4 (64 bit).
I have deployed in the local network of my client and executing the test page on a Windows 7 computer, without ant DLL added to the installation... it works fine everytime.  Can I gives more help? write me. Fabrizio (Italy)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the OCX browser control is registered properly with Windows & in the same way as on your development machine. If memory is right it has a key like 'Browser.Control.1' or something like that.